# Acessing file from physical location securely

Tags: c#, .net, file, internet-explorer

I have a .docx file stored at one of the physical disk. Now from c# code I am trying to access.File is accessible but internet explorer is giving a warning message like "Only Secure content is displayed"

Here is the code

```
 string fileLocation = new Uri(vpathwithPageNum).LocalPath; // Value = `//Servername/Detail/abc.docx
 File.SetAttributes(fileLocation, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

File location is like `file://Servername/Detail/abc.docx`. If I try to read file like `//Servername/Detail/abc.docx`, its saying content cant be displayed.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `LocalPath`?

Comment: @rbr94 By using this I was able to make file readonly

Comment: @rbr94 Any Suggestions?

Comment: what's in `vpathwithPageNum`?

Comment: Does it look like this: `file://Servername/Detail/abc.docx`?

Comment: @rbr94 Yes.Exactly same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124532/discussion-between-lara-and-rbr94).