# Physical file path issue in c#

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, file-handling

I have a file which is stored at a physical disk say `var path = file://Servername/SampleFiles/abc.docx`. Now when I am trying to add this into below code

```
 File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
```

With above line of code I am getting `URI file format is not supported` whereas if I am trying to add path like `var path = //Servername/SampleFiles/abc.docx` then above line is working fine but I am getting a prompt on Internet Explorer as `Only Secure content is displayed`

Please guide guide me to remove the IE prompt, I don't want users to disable it from IE, as it will be security issues.

Comment: How IE is involved here?

Comment: The error message is telling you **URI file format is not supported**, looks like a smoking gun to me

Comment: Also, a file path should contain 3 /'s. `file:///Servername/SampleFiles/abc.docx`

Comment: As per [File URIs in Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows/) a file URI path that **doesn't** include the host name must have three slashes, file URIs that **do** include the host must use two slashes.

Comment: @Evk I am getting `Only Secure Content is displayed prompt` in IE

Comment: @Nsevens Will slash be `/` or `\` backword  ?

Comment: @Lara for file url's it's `forward /`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme
@stuartd I had no idea. Thank you.

Comment: But when implementing you use \

Comment: @stuartd Any reason why I am getting the prompt on IE after adding the code shared with the post to make file read only?

Comment: You've got your slashes the wrong way round, as other commenters pointed out  - the path should be `\\Servername\SampleFiles\abc.docx` or you can use `string localPath = new Uri(path).LocalPath;` to convert it from the File URI

Comment: @stuartd I am using exactly the same path as you mentioned. Concern is why I am getting prompt message in IE.Please give your comments

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2625928

Comment: What exact line of code are you running that invokes IE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acessing file from physical location securely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39766936/acessing-file-from-physical-location-securely)

Comment: Don't ask the same thing twice